# How to simulate bimodal distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution

I have the following code to generate bimodal distribution but when I graph the histogram. I don't see the 2 modes.  I am wondering if there's something wrong with my code.

```
mu1 <- log(1)   
mu2 <- log(10)
sig1 <- log(3)
sig2 <- log(3)
cpct <- 0.4   

bimodalDistFunc <- function (n,cpct, mu1, mu2, sig1, sig2) {
  y0 <- rlnorm(n,mean=mu1, sd = sig1)
  y1 <- rlnorm(n,mean=mu2, sd = sig2)

  flag <- rbinom(n,size=1,prob=cpct)
  y <- y0*(1 - flag) + y1*flag 
}

bimodalData <- bimodalDistFunc(n=100,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)
hist(log(bimodalData))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be just too small `n` and too small difference between `mu1` and `mu2`, taking `mu1=log(1)`, `mu2=log(50)` and `n=10000` gives this:

[image]

Comment: Also using more than the default number of bins helps e.g. `hist(log(bimodalData), breaks=100)`