# R - produce data with certain shape between -1 and 1

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I tried to produce data in R that is distributed like on this image:

[image]

The values should really lie only between -1 and +1 but less should be between -1 and 0 compared to 0 and +1.

Comment: Well, I tried playing around with the rnorm function setting different parameters and then merging the data together but never really looked like on that image :/

Comment: See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530010/how-to-simulate-bimodal-distribution-in-r/11530222) question.

Comment: Thanks Julius. that solved my problem. That was actually what I was looking for. great!

Answer (score -1):

You need do this:

1) Discover a function that have this shape (like (-(x-1)*x^2*(x+1)*(x+2))*k)
2) Integrate it in the interval -1 to 1 (it will be a function of k)
3) Match this integration to 1 (to discover K)
4) Sample a number between 0 and 1 (let's call this number z)
5) Discover y that the integrate of you function from 0 to y give z
6) Repeat tons of time steps 4-5